# How to remove the white space from a ToscaWidgets2 - twc.forms SingleSelect

Tags: python, turbogears2, toscawidgets

I'm using Tosca Widgets 2 on a TurboGears 2 Project,

Does anyone know how to remove the ‘prompt_text’ attribute while instancing a twf.SingleSelectField?

```
year = twf.SingleSelectField(label="choose a year",options = range(now.year-35,now.year))
```

What I get in my form is a select element with the values and the first option is an empty option.
I want it removed but I don't know how..

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `prompt_text` property to `None`. It should remove the default entry injected by prompt_text.